# refreshing part of the page with a partial in rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a cart that contains items, in the checkout page these items can be reviews and their quantity cna be changed. I want to add a button that, when clicked, will refresh the partial that is rendering the cart thus updating totals etc.
I have created the button and it changes the innerHtml its supposed to (when I test it with ("test") instead of the <% j render...%>, however it will not update the cart (reload the partial).
Heres my code

Route
`get 'refresh_cart', to: 'carts#refresh'`

Controller

```
def refresh
    @cart = Cart.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js  {}
    end
  end
```

html

```
<div class="container-fluid cart-submit" id="cart-item-partial">
  <%= render 'cartItems' %>
</div>
```

refresh.js.erb

```
cart_items = document.getElementById("cart-item-partial")
cart_items.innerHTML = <%= j render 'cartItems'%>
```

Comment: Also, when i click the "refresh" button I get a call to the server.

```
tarted GET "/refresh_cart" for ::1 at 2021-01-15 11:00:23 -0300
Processing by CartsController#refresh as JS
....
  ↳ app/helpers/products_helper.rb:22:in `quantity_helper'
  Rendered carts/_cartSubtotal.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 30)
  Rendered carts/_cartItems.html.erb (Duration: 32.7ms | Allocations: 10441)
  Rendered carts/refresh.js.erb (Duration: 34.3ms | Allocations: 11239)
Completed 200 OK in 42ms (Views: 33.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms | Allocations: 1)
```

However the page does not change

Answer (score 0):

So, in case you have been stuck in this for hours (like I was), the problem is that you must surround j render statement with double quotes

`cart_items.innerHTML = <%= j render 'cartItems'%>`

should be

`cart_items.innerHTML = "<%= j render 'cartItems'%>"`